# Marking stored vector layer as exported?

Tags: pyqgis, layers, vector, export

Through PyQGIS using `QgsVectorFileWriter.writeAsVectorFormat()` we can store a vector layer as .gpkg, is great!

However, once we close the project and reopen it again, the layer name is showed but their associated gpkg data are lost.
QGIS provide [a way](https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html#creating-a-new-temporary-scratch-layer) to permanently store a memory layer on disk, but it seems this is a manual process through the QGIS tool environment (context menu on every layer).

I'd like to export the layer using `writeAsVectorFormat()` but as next stemp mark it as exported, so it would be available in the future even if I close the project.
Therefore, the 'memory icon' would disappear too.

Does anybody know it this is feasible using PyQGIS?

Comment: "... it seems this is a manual process through the tool." What tool?

Comment: I meant using QGIS environment, through the contextual menu on every layer.
Currently I'm having a look to this related entry, maybe could be a solution, but this is not through pyqgis: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/127389/what-is-a-memory-vector-layer-in-qgis
Thanks @wingnut

Answer (score 1):

One approach to do it. Check if in memory layer, run processing script to save your "in memory" layer, change memory layer datasource and save your project.

In your case, you need to adapt my code to reuse infos like datasource path and layer name after your `writeAsVectorFormat` export

```py
project = QgsProject.instance()
project_dir_path = project.readPath("./")

for layer in project.mapLayers().values():
    if layer.type() == QgsMapLayer.VectorLayer and layer.dataProvider().name() == 'memory':
        # We do not manage sanitized name colision (if your
        # layer name is the same, code will try to write to
        # a GPKG with the same name and the same layer...)
        layer_name = layer.name().lower().replace(' ', '_')
        out = processing.run("native:savefeatures", {
            'INPUT': iface.activeLayer(),
            'OUTPUT': f'{project_dir_path}/{layer_name}.gpkg',
            'LAYER_NAME':'',
            'DATASOURCE_OPTIONS':'',
            'LAYER_OPTIONS':''}
        )
        layer.setDataSource(f"{out['OUTPUT']}|layername={layer_name}", layer.name(), 'ogr')
project.write()
```

Comment: Great Thomas!, this code snippet works, it associates the gpkg stored file with the layer available on memory, changing the 'memory icon' status associated to every layer.
I am very grateful to you, thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: BTW, it would be fine to overwrite the .gpkg file in case it already exits, pls, Do you know any paramter for this? Thx!